# How can I change the behavior of array printing in Python?

Tags: python, list

When I print an array:

```
 pi = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5]
 print pi
```

It prints like normal:

```
 [3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5]
```

I was wondering if I could print like:

```
 314159265
```

If so how?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> pi = [3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5]
>>> print ''.join(map(str, pi))
314159265
```

Or `print` function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  #not required in Python 3
>>> print(*pi, sep='')
314159265
```